# Replace part of email body from combo-box

Tags: vba, outlook, combobox

I want to replace a just part of body from an email with a value selected from a drop-list. Any help is welcomed.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Subject 1"
    .AddItem "Subject 2"
    .AddItem "Subject 3"
End With

End Sub
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    lstNo = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the mail open this replaces "Test" in the body.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim curritem As mailItem

    Set curritem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    curritem.Body = Replace(curritem.Body, "Test", ComboBox1.Value)

    ' or
    ' curritem.HTMLBody = Replace(curritem.HTMLBody, "Test", ComboBox1.Value)

    Set curritem = Nothing

    Unload Me

End Sub
```